# Why Angular guard is running before ngOnInit?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have `checkAuth` function in `ngOnInit` in `app.component.ts` which checks localStorage for token and if token is valid authService logs you in.

Also, I have AuthGuard in `/profile` route which checks if you logged in.

If I click the link in the navbar this works great, but if I go to link directly authGuard working before my `checkAuth` function and returns false.

Where do I need to place my `checkAuth` function to make it work correctly?
Or maybe I need to change something in AuthGuard or in app.component

Here is AuthGuard code

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn:'root'
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate, CanActivateChild {

  constructor(private auth:AuthService, private router:Router) {
  }

  canActivate(route:ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state:RouterStateSnapshot):Observable<boolean>{
    console.log(this.auth.isAuth)
    console.log(this.auth.isLoggedIn())
    if (this.auth.isLoggedIn()){
      return of(true)
    } else {
      this.router.navigate(['/login'])
      return of(false)
    }
  }

  canActivateChild(route:ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state:RouterStateSnapshot):Observable<boolean>{
    return this.canActivate(route, state)
  }
}
```

app.component

```js
ngOnInit() {
    if (localStorage.getItem('token')){
      this.auth.checkAuth().subscribe(
        (data) => {
          console.log(data)
          console.log(this.auth.isAuth)
        }
      )
    }
  }
```

and checkAuth in AuthService

```js
checkAuth():Observable<UserDto>{
     return this.http.get<UserDto>(`/api/user/refresh`, {withCredentials:true, observe:'body', responseType:'json'})
        .pipe(
          tap(
            (data) => {
              localStorage.setItem('token', data.accessToken)
              this.setAuth(true)
              this.setUser(data.user)
            },
            (error) => {
              console.log(error)
            }
          )
        )
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want `checkAuth` to run before the guard, you have to make it a guard as well, and use it before the guard that you already have. E.g: `canActivate: [CheckAuthGuard, AuthGuard]`.

This is what's going on right now:

**First scenario - accessing `/profile` by clicking in the navbar**

1. You access the application's root component
2. Whatever guards you have on the root route run
3. The root component is initialized and `AppComponent.ngOnInit()` runs, thus running `checkAuth()`
4. You click the link in the navbar to go the `/profile` route
5. Guards for the profile route are run

**Second scenario - accessing `/profile` by visiting the URL directly**

1. You access the application's root component, but this time it is routed to the `/profile` route
2. Whatever guards you have on the profile route run
3. The root component and it's child are initialized, running their `ngOnInit()` methods

See? In the second scenario, the guard runs before ngOnInit and `checkAuth`. I advise you to put some `console.log` calls on your app, so you can more easily see the order in which things are happening.

Basically this is it, guards run before the component is rendered, so you should keep that in mind. Extract your `checkAuth` call to a guard and you'll be fine.